# Heroku Postgres fails to pull and push on windows

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

As you read it, the problem is simple as that. I figured out the solution myself so I'm posting this question for our fellows out there struggling with heroku postgres.
Describing my problem:
I have the same PostgreSQL version on my local machine and Heroku app.

1. push and pull: the cli run until it came to the

```
pg_restore:  processing data for table "public.posts"
pg_restore: error: unrecognized data block type (0) while searching archive
 !    pg_restore errored with 1
```

2. I tried to work around for the **push** problem with `pg_dump` my local db and then use `heroku pg:backups:restore <backup file url> -a my-app` as Heroku instructed in their blog. I did 99% the same with the instructions from Heroku themselves, only with 1 small change that I didn't have my output dump file named *file.dump* as they did. Actually there's no file extension at all, in order for the `pg:backups:restore` to work.
3. Another problem was actually getting my local db synced with heroku, manually of course, the `pull` didn't work out as mentioned in #1. So I made a backup of my heroku app database with `pg:backups:capture` and download it with `pg:backups:download`. Things could work out but it was the credentials stopped me to restore my local db with that backup file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#2 is solved completely. #1 and #3 need future updates from Heroku after they accepting my issue tickets.

Comment: Same problem, I did "heroku run pg_restore --version" but nothing changes. Anybody found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Having the same "pg_restore errored with 1" issue with Heroku pg:push and Postgresql 13.1.
Local system:

> pg_restore --version
> pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 13.1

Heroku response:
heroku run pg_restore --version
Running pg_restore --version on ⬢ ... up, run.5138 (Free)
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 12.5 (Ubuntu 12.5-1.pgdg18.04+1)

even though:

> heroku pg:info
> === DATABASE_URL
> Plan:                  Hobby-dev
> Status:                Available
> Connections:           0/20
> PG Version:            13.1
> Created:               2020-12-31 01:55 UTC
> Data Size:             8.0 MB

Seems like Heroku has a mismatched version for pg_restore of 12.5 for postgresql of 13.1.

Comment: Yeah they really do have some problems with the pg_restore.